# GSS-API Exception - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - AES128

Tags: java, encryption, gssapi

I'm writing a UserAuthGss for a ssh client using Java 6. The server, after receiving the first client token calls GSSContext.acceptSecContext on that token. The Server is throwing this exception:

> GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level:
> Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to
> decrypt AP REP - AES128 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96)

Found http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6907425 in Java 7 and wondering if anyone has had similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for me was to use a different algorithm in my kdc configuration.

Comment: may i know how did you do that exactly?  I am having similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the keytab file is not containing the required encryption types, generating a new keytab file would help using `/crypto ALL` with the `ktpass` command:

```
ktpass /out "server.keytab" /crypto ALL /princ HTTP/server@REALM /mapuser KERBEROS_SERVICEUSER /pass PASSWORD /ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL
```

Replace `HTTP/server@REALM`, `KERBEROS_SERVICEUSER` and `PASSWORD` with according values.